# url has /errorpath

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an issue when I try to access an ASPX page. This aspx page has nothing but the page attribute with codeFile and inherits. Its corresponding aspx.cs file has the code that writes to the aspx file. Everything works fine in my Dev enviornment. When I try to deploy the same in test server and access the page by clicking an hyperlink, I get the foll url

```
 http://tb..hosting.net/review/Search.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/review/Create-xml-writer.aspx
```

and lands in search.aspx instead of Create-xml-writer.aspx

But the url should be,

```
http://tb.hosting.net/review/Create-xml-writer.aspx
```

I did a couple of build and deployed. Still i get the same issue. What does this errorpath=/ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errorpath part is something that gets passed into a custom error page when an error occurs in ASP.Net, it contains the path of the page that has the problem.

Is search.aspx defined as a custom error page in your web.config file? Turn custom errors off in your web.config file and you should see the actual error message.